# How to add custom music for a Minecraft mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am semi-new to modding (in) Minecraft, I already have a bit of experience in java and I know the basics of modding like, how to add blocks and items. My idea is to make a mod that will add new music instead of the music vanilla already has.

What I was thinking was,

- If you walk into a desert biome - then desert-type music would play,
- Or if your player goes to sleep - nightmare-ish music would play,
- When you are fighting a boss, then epic boss music would play.

I was also thinking of adding custom sounds for different things and items, like when you are using a crafting table. This would make the game's sound effects more realistic.

Also in mind am planning to use the following prerequisites:

- It is a mod, not a resource pack,
- It is going to use 1.7.2 Forge.

I have no idea how to do this and I can't find a decent tutorial.